# Trimming down skobbler map size & offering download alternatives

Tags: ios, size, skmaps

We're making offline road-trip planner.
We want to use skobbler maps but the main issue is that the framework is way too big.

Even with some trimming down options, it's still over 110Mb (only with skobbler framework).

Inside SKMaps.framework there is a document SKMaps with 95Mb is size.
No program can open this document (at least no program i have on my mac atm).

I was wondering what might be in this document and is it possible to 'open' it and remove unnecessary files from it.

I am asking this because when I launch my app with skobbler in it, there is a map of entire world available to explore. 
I don't need that. I only need several states in the US and that's it. One state is roughly 30Mb in size, which is acceptable and download option for each state can be an asset, so a user downloads only what he needs.

IF there is no way of deleting entire world map from framework, what are my other options?

Can this file SKMaps, with 96Mb in size be downloaded after a user launches an app, so I don't have a huge app on the app store?
Can i write and launch my app without SKMaps in the app bundle from the start, and I make the user download it once he starts an app for the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the SkMaps.bundle and this will impact the .framework object.

Indeed, the unpacked size will be > 100 MB but when packing it (generating the .ipa file) it will only add ~20MB to the final app file (i.e. compiling the demo project without audio advices and only 1 style, targeting both armv7 and arm64 will generate a .ipa file of ~ 19.4)

By default the demo app does not "contain" any maps - it connects to the servers and downloads the map from there.

If you'd like to download "offline maps" - see the "Maps.json and downloads" example in the demo app. 
If you're intent is to "prebundle" an offline map within your app see: http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/creating-an-app-with-a-pre-bundled-map/